# filter data Firebase Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i have the following structure in firebase realtime with the Reactjs:

-contact
--id
--data
--name
--status
--valor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMXJK.png)

I'm trying to get these items with the script:

```
const teste = (value) => {
   
    fireDb.child("contacts").orderByChild("status").equalTo("Receita").on("value", (snapshot)  => {
        
        if(snapshot.val()) {       
                     
            const data = snapshot.val();
            
            setData(data);
            
        }
    }

   )};
   console.log(teste());
```

however in the console it always returns "undefined".

How can I filter all items that have the same "status" and list it in the page's HTML?

Comment: Have you tried unfiltering first and getting the first method to render data followed by  the next. `fireDb.child("contacts")` followed by adding `.equalTo("Receita")`. Your equal to may be incorrect

Comment: I put: 

const teste= (value) => {
     fireDb.child("contacts").equalTo("Receita").on('value', function(snapshot) { 
        if(snapshot.val()) {                
            const data= snapshot.val();
            setData(data);
                      
        }
      
     }
     ) }; console.log(teste());

and it didn't work :(

Comment: Update and paste the full file. What parts are working?

Comment: I put all the code here

https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/uvalavesac.js

the question line is from 98 to 109.

Comment: What does your firebaseDb file look like? Can you narrow it down to the portion that is not working?

Comment: the part that is not working is described above. Only that part that is not working :/